# Aligning buttons to center, what am i doing worng?

Tags: java, html, css, dashboard, node-red

Anyone smart here, who can see why I can't align my buttons?
I've been trying over the course of 2 days now and I still don't know what's wrong, last time I asked here my question got deleted and I couldn't figure out what to do after that, 'm still a complete beginner...
I've tried Items-aligned, but it shortens the width of the button which I can't seem to change...

```
<style id="remote-buttons">
:root {
  --dashboard-unit-width: 48px;
  --dashboard-unit-height: 48px;
}
.nr-dashboard-template {
    padding: 0px;
    
}
.remote-button:not([disabled]):hover{
     background-color: #4CAF50 !important;
}

/*   This is the normal button definition  */
.remote-button{
    background-color: MediumSeaGreen !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    height: var(--dashboard-unit-height);
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size:1.0em;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 36px;
    min-width: unset;
    line-height: unset;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you create a minimally reproducible example? Including html and css? Because no-one is going to be able to help you without it. Centering a button is usually extremely simple. The reason none of the given solutions fail you is that you haven’t provided the part that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `margin: 0 auto;` and `display: block;`

```css
.remote-button{
    background-color: MediumSeaGreen !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    height: var(--dashboard-unit-height);
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size:1.0em;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin: 0 auto;   /* Added this */
    display: block;   /* Added this */
    text-align: center; /* Added this */
    min-height: 36px;
    min-width: unset;
    line-height: unset;
}
```

Comment: hmm i tried it doenst seem to do the trick, it looks the same... I've manually changes the widget-size for the buttons to 1x4, could this be problematic?

Comment: @Brokhus i'll update my answer. Hope it works now!

Answer (score 0):

You can center easily by giving the container `text-align: center;` but for better solution please attach the html code or put it in https://codepen.io/

Comment: I hope this doesnt come across too stupid, but ive tried putting the code up in the question? where would it be a good idea to put the text-align:center? ive tried it many times but cant make it seem to work

Comment: I used this template for the button... '<div>
   <md-button class="md-button remote-button"
        ng-click="send({payload})"   
        data-topic="home"
        data-payload="home" 
        aria-label="home"
        color=white
    >Serialnumber
   </md-button>

</div>
'

Answer (score 0):

Try it with

`margin: 0 auto;`

and to align the text centered

`text-align: center;`